# Node Multer diskStorage filename not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, multer

I'm using the diskStorage engine to assign the destination and filename to images being received by my API. Here is my code:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const multer = require('multer')
const destination = 'imgs/'
const filename = (req, file, cb) =>{cb(null, new Date().toISOString + '_' + file.originalname)}
const storage = multer.diskStorage({destination, filename})
const upload = multer({storage: storage})

const Imagen = require('../dataaccess/model/Imagen')
```

Everything works fine except the naming of my file. Instead of my file being named something like:

```
'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ_file.jpeg'
```

it's named:

```
'function toISOString() { [native code] }_t1.jpg'
```

Below is the endpoint code:

```
router.post('/img/new', upload.single('newImage'), async (req, res)=>{

    /**
     * Validación de la existencia del archivo en la petición
     */
     if(!req.file){
         res.status(400).json({
             'message' : 'Error en los parámetros. No hay ningún archivo.',
             'req' : res.body,
         })
     }

    var username = req.body.username;
    let fecha = new Date();

    /**
     * Validación de los parámetros obligatorios
     */

     if(!username || !fecha){
         res.status(400).json({
             'mensaje' : 'Parámetros incompletos',
             'error' : err
         })
         return 
     }

     /**
      * Creación del nuevo Objeto Imagen
      */
     var img = new Imagen({
         username: username,
         fecha: fecha,
         path: req.file.path
     })

     await img.save( function (err, doc){
         if(err){
             res.status(500).json({
                 'mensaje' : 'Hubo un error al subir la imagen',
                 'error' : error
             })
             console.error(err)
             return
         }
         res.json(doc)
     })
}),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this line `const filename = (req, file, cb) =>{cb(null, new Date().toISOString + '_' + file.originalname)};`. You are not calling `toISOString` function. Your code should look like this:

```
const filename = (req, file, cb) =>{cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '_' + file.originalname)};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep... I was missing that, I don't know how I didn't notice. Thanks.